# Issue in date formating while importing excel file in R

Tags: r

I am trying to get the date as `Jan 20` to `June 20` in the month column of rpivottable. but it's always showing in yyyy-mm-dd format e.g. `2020-01-01`. My code as below:

```
    library(readxl)
    library(rpivotTable) 
    myexcel <- read_excel("claimH1data_date.xlsx")
    x <- myexcel$Month
    as.Date(x, format, tryFormats = c("%m-%Y"),tz = "UTC",
    optional = TRUE)
    format(x, format="%B %Y")
    View(x)
    rpivotTable(myexcel, rows = "Month",cols="Action", vals = "Freq", 
    aggregatorName = "Count", rendererName = "Table")
```

Can you please help? Thanks.

Comment: Try : `myexcel$Month <- format(myexcel$Month, format="%B %Y")` and then use `rpivotTable`

Comment: Yes...working but not showing chronologically. Showing alphabetically. Desired output is Jan 20 to June 20. But showing Apr 20 Feb 20 Jan 20 June 20 March 20 May 20

Comment: Hi Shweta, did you read the link which I shared with you (twice) to share data? Let me add it once again http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 . If you need help please add data using `dput`.

Comment: Yes Ronak but I am a new user here.  I read the link which you have provided but not getting how to use the dput() function and why. I just need to paste my code. Kindly help.

Comment: You can run `dput(head(myexcel, 10))` in the R console and copy the output by editing your post. After you do that also show your expected output for the data shared. Please edit your post and don't add data in comments. An example of `dput` output is in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64799485/construct-a-loop-based-on-multiple-conditions-in-a-column-r

Comment: OK. I ran dput(myexcel$Month) in R console and here is the output:                                > dput(myexcel$Month)
c("January 20", "January 20", "January 20", "January 20", "January 20", 
"February 20", "February 20", "February 20", "February 20", "February 20", 
"March 20", "March 20", "March 20", "March 20", "March 20",
"April 20", "April 20", "April 20", "April 20", "April 20",
"May 20", "May 20", "May 20", "May 20", "May 20"
"June 20", "June 20", "June 20", "June 20", "June 20")

Answer (score 0):

You can try :

```
library(readxl)
#Read the data
myexcel <- read_excel("claimH1data_date.xlsx")
#Sort the data based on date
myexcel <- myexcel[order(myexcel$Month), ]
#Apply the format
myexcel$Month <- format(myexcel$Month, format="%B %Y")
myexcel
```

Comment: still showing alphabetically in "Viewer" window .But when I View myexcel in code window its working . but not in rpivottable

Comment: @Shweta Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Please add data editing your post it is not possible to copy data from your comments. It would be easier to help if you read this post first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269 on how to share data.

Comment: Current output : Showing months column alphabetically   : Apr20 to May 20  Expected output : trying to show months column chronologically : Jan 20 to June 20

Comment: library(readxl)
library(rpivotTable)
#Read the data
myexcel <- read_excel("claimH1data_date.xlsx")
#Sort the data based on date
myexcel <- myexcel[order(myexcel$Month), ]
#Apply the format
myexcel$Month <- format(myexcel$Month, format="%B %y")
rpivotTable(myexcel, rows = "Month",cols="Action",aggregatorName = "Count", rendererName = "Table")